# Curses errors with C++ classes

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include "color.h"
#include <curses.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace ConsoleColor;
namespace color = ConsoleColor;

int i, n;
char input, white_space = 250, obstacle_default = 219, player=1, up_key=119, down_key=115, left_key=97, right_key=100;

class box {
    int x, y, pos, pos_x, pos_y, area;
    vector<int> obstacles;
    public:
        box (int,int);
        void print (void);
        void move (void);
        void set_obstacles (vector<int> v);
};

int main()
{
    box main_hallway(50,10);
    vector<int> obstacle_list={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40};
    main_hallway.set_obstacles(obstacle_list);
    main_hallway.move();
    return 0;
}
    [...]
```

With the above code, after including curses.h from the pdcurses libs, I immediately get these two errors:

27: error: expected ';' before 'main_hallway'
28: error: 'main_hallway' was not declared in this scope

The code worked perfectly beforehand, but with pdcurses added...it seems it doesn't like to agree with classes. Is there a way to fix this?

**Additional Info:**
-- Windows Vista Professional
-- Code::Blocks 10.04+MinGW32
-- [PDCurses 3.4](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/&rct=j&q=pdcurses.sourceforge.net&ei=6Z-KTf3UOuyD0QGP5pSADg&usg=AFQjCNGWw0__gChibFLBRsUcUEE0mFHltw&cad=rja)

Comment: There is no error in what you have shown. Error is in the code what isn't posted. Post the entire code snippet before `main()` if it isn't too large.

Comment: I've edited the main post to include everything above and including int main()

Comment: @Captain - Only system headers needed to be in `<>`. So, try this `#include "curses.h"`.

Comment: Same result, no differences. Is it possible that pdcurses just isn't compatible with classes?

Comment: @Captain - Now do the weirdest thing. Place both #include "curses.h" and #include "color.h" at the beginning lines of the program.

Comment: I actually got a new error that way. Weird. "error: macro "getch" passed 1 arguments, but takes just 0"

Comment: After some tweaking I realized the only includes I really need are curses.h, color.h, and vector. Problem still not resolved though.

Answer (score 1):

Presumable, there's a #define in pdcurses that defines some token in here. I'm guessing for `move` or `print`. Use cl /e on WIndows to see what's coming out of the preprocessor.

Comment: Haha, my apologies, I meant to bold it but I guess you can't bold quoted text. I'll edit that out. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: "warning: statement is a reference, not call, to function 'box'", and "warning: statement has no effect" both popped up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, I needed to declare my class like so:

```
class x {
} y;
```

rather than:

```
class x{
};
int main()
{
   x y;
}
```